# Add text description under each image in image viewpager

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager, layout-inflater

As galley class deprecated so i try to substitute it with viewpager class , i already created my **image viewpager** and work nicely .

now im trying to add **text description under each image** , i googled alot about that with no result ,im try to use **LayoutInflater** with **custom layout** but end with nothing , it doesnt show the text .

**note:** this is the first time to use viewpager and try to customize it , so my code below in attempt to inflater the layout and customize it with viewpager, maybe wrong or need more adjustment ,coz of no experiance in that .

any advice will be appreciated to achieve that ,thanks.

My Code :

**ImagePager:**

```
 public class ImagePager extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ImagePagerAdapter adapter = new ImagePagerAdapter(this, imageArra);
    ViewPager myPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.myimagepager);
    myPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    myPager.setCurrentItem(0);}

      private int imageArra[] = { R.drawable.a, R.drawable.b, R.drawable.c,
                       R.drawable.d, R.drawable.e, R.drawable.f,
                                 R.drawable.g, R.drawable.h, R.drawable.i, 
                                 R.drawable.j, R.drawable.k};}
```

**ImagePagerAdapter:**

```
  public class ImagePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

Activity activity;
int imageArray[];

public ImagePagerAdapter(Activity act, int[] imgArra) {
    imageArray = imgArra;
    activity = act;   }

public int getCount() {
    return imageArray.length;   }

public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)collection.getContext().
          getSystemService (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_pager, null);

    layout.findViewById(R.id.caption);

 ImageView view = new ImageView(activity);                      
    view.setPadding(5, 25, 5, 5);
    view.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_START);
    view.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    ((ViewPager) collection).addView(view, 0);
    return view;   }

@Override
public void destroyItem(View arg0, int arg1, Object arg2) {
    ((ViewPager) arg0).removeView((View) arg2);   }

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View arg0, Object arg1) {
    return arg0 == ((View) arg1);   }

@Override
public Parcelable saveState() {
    return null;   }
                }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here

```
public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)collection.getContext().getSystemService
             (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_pager, null);

    layout.findViewById(R.id.caption);

 ImageView view = new ImageView(activity);                      
    view.setPadding(5, 25, 5, 5);
    view.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_START);
    view.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    ((ViewPager) collection).addView(view, 0);
    return view;   }
```

In `cutome_pager` design your View like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/gallery_imageView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/gallery_imageView_dsc"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:text="Hello...." />
```

and

```
public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)collection.getContext().getSystemService
             (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_pager, null);

                    ImageView im=(ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.gallery_imageView);
                    im.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                    TextView dsc=(TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.gallery_imageView_dsc);
                    ((ViewPager) collection).addView(layout, 0);
                    return layout;   }
```

Comment: @M Mohsin Naeem thanks alot for your replay but when run app it show only textview without image as black screen show the text at the buttom only any advice , thaanks

Comment: you need to assign an image to your `ImageView`. you can use `im.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);`

Comment: @M Mohsin Naeem ImageView view = new ImageView(activity);  this is not work also, any advice my dear

Comment: dear `mageView view = new ImageView(activity);` as you did not add this to any `View`. See my edits

Comment: @M Mohsin Naeem my dear im.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED); will show red background instead of images

Comment: ~ah use this `im.setImageDrawable(imageArra[position]);`

Comment: @M Mohsin Naeem i do it like this : im.setImageResource(imageArray[position]); its work and image appear , but all has the same text , i want to specify different text for each image , any advice my master

Comment: for dynamic test you also need an array like `imageArra[]` e.g `imageDsc[]` and set text in the code like `dsc.setText(imageDsc[position])`

Answer (score 0):

In the `instantiateItem()` method you creating a `ImageView` and adding it to view pager and returning it. In this method create one `LinearLayout` with vertical orientation and then create one `ImageView` and one `TextView` for the description, then add the `ImageView` and the `TextView` to `LineaLayout` and the add `LinearLayout` to view pager and also return the `LinearLayout`..